# How can i use cassandra for checkpointing in spark structured streaming instead of a fike system like s3 Or hdfs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Hi i want to use cassandra instead of hdds compatible fike system to do checkpointing in my spark streaming job, how can i do it?

I have followed spark documentation but unable to find anything,didn't even find any online link to do so

Comment: I suggest to read the article [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Did you get an error trying to do that? show what you did and if it is possible try to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you following a tutorial or doc, put the link too